# Алгоритм группировки по пересекающимся диапазонам дат

Tags: алгоритм, дата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучший алгоритм для группировки данных по пересекающимся диапазонам дат.

Входные данные: Массив объектов, состоящих из трех полей: start (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД), end (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД), name.
Входные данные отсортированы по start.

Выходные данные: Массив объектов, состоящих из трех полей: start (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД), end (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД), data (массив).

Пример входных данных:

```
[
    {
        start: 2021-10-01,
        end: 2022-10-01,
        name: data_1
    },
    {
        start: 2021-11-01,
        end: 2022-02-01,
        name: data_2
    },
    {
        start: 2021-12-01,
        end: 2022-01-01,
        name: data_3
    }
]
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
[
    {
        start: 2021-10-01,
        end: 2021-10-31,
        data:
        [
            data_1
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2021-11-01,
        end: 2021-11-30,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2021-12-01,
        end: 2022-01-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2,
            data_3
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2022-01-02,
        end: 2022-02-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1,
            data_2,
        ]
    },
    {
        start: 2022-02-02,
        end: 2022-10-01,
        data:
        [
            data_1
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Сгребаешь все даты в кучу, не глядя, начало это или конец. Сортируешь, выбрасываешь дубликаты. После чего для каждой последовательной пары дат выбираешь те исходные записи, которые накрывают диапазон для этой пары. Всё.

Comment: @Akina вот этой даты `2021-10-31` в исходном наборе вообще нет.

Comment: @tym32167 Этой даты нет, потому что в моем случае выходные даты не должны "перекрываться". Но это уже тонкости. Алгоритм, предложенный уважаемым Akina, кажется очень подходящим. За что ему огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Akina Большое спасибо Вам за ответ! У меня остался вопрос по перекрытию дат. В моем случае необходимо, чтобы перекрывающихся дат не было, т.е. "end" предыдущего объекта не был равен "start" последующего. К сожалению, не могу сообразить, как это реализовать. Буду очень благодарен, если что-то подскажете. Спасибо!

Comment: *В моем случае необходимо, чтобы перекрывающихся дат не было, т.е. "end" предыдущего объекта не был равен "start" последующего.* Т.е. если есть две исходные записи 1-10 (1) и 10-20 (2), то на выходе должно быть три записи 1-9 (1), 10-10 (1,2) и 11-20 (2), так?

Comment: @Akina да, всё верно

Comment: Значит, при удалении дубликатов просто добавляйте в список даты "начало минус день", если они отсутствуют.

Comment: @Akina К сожалению, такой алгоритм не сработает в таком случае:
1 запись 1-30 (1)
2 запись 5-15 (2)
На выходе должно быть :
1-4(1): 1 запись, 5-15(2): 1+2 запись, 16-30(3): 1 запись

Comment: Ну добавьте ещё "конец плюс день"...